# Where are these behaviors defined in the Makefile?

Tags: c, makefile

I'm trying to reuse code from a public repository. But there are some problems when I use it.

The address of the repository is:   https://github.com/0xADE1A1DE/Mastik
According to the README document, the directory structure after compilation is:

```
├── bin
    ├── build
    │   ├── bin
    │   ├── include
    │   │   └── mastik
    │   ├── lib
    │   └── share
    │       └── mastik
    │           └── tools
    │               └── doubloon
    │                   └── data
    │                       └── icons
    ├── demo
    ├── docs
    │   └── doubloon
    ├── mastik
    ├── src
    ├── tests
    └── tools
        └── Doubloon
            ├── data
            │   └── icons
            └── src
```

I am compiling under the demo directory. The Makefiles in this directory are:

```
FILES= \
    CB-hist.c \
    FF-gnupg-1.4.13.c \
    FF-trace.c \
    FR-1-file-access.c \
    FR-2-file-access.c \
    FR-flush.c \
    FR-function-call-nodelay.c \
    FR-function-call.c \
    FR-gnupg-1.4.13.c \
    FR-threshold.c \
    L1-capture.c \
    L1-rattle.c \
    L3-capture.c \
    L3-capturecount.c \
    L3-scan.c \
    L2-capture.c \
    L2-rattle.c \
    L2-sequence.c \
    ST-L2PP-AES.c
    

prefix=/usr/local/src/cache_side_channel/Mastik-main/build
exec_prefix=${prefix}

FTARGETS=$(FILES:.c=) 
FOBJS=${FILES:.c=.o}
#CFLAGS=-g -std=gnu99 -I..
CFLAGS=-g -O2   -I..
LDFLAGS=-L../src/ -g
LDLIBS=-lmastik -ldwarf -lelf -lbfd 

TARGETS=${FTARGETS} ST-L1PP-AES ST-L2PP-AES
OBJS=${FOBJS} ST-L1PP-AES.o aes_core.o

all: ${TARGETS}

install:

${FTARGETS}: %: %.o 
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ $@.o ${LDLIBS}

ST-L1PP-AES: ST-L1PP-AES.o aes_core.o
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ ST-L1PP-AES.o aes_core.o ${LDLIBS}
    
ST-L2PP-AES: ST-L2PP-AES.o aes_core.o
    ${CC} ${LDFLAGS} -o $@ ST-L2PP-AES.o aes_core.o ${LDLIBS}

clean:
    rm -f ${TARGETS} ${OBJS} *.sig out

distclean: clean
    rm Makefile config.h
```

1. Before running make, there is no `.o` file in the folder, and there is no command to generate a .o file in this Makefile, only the command to generate executable files from the `.o` file. However, when executing, the `.o` file will be generated first, and the executable file will be generated. Where is the control to generate `.o` files?
2. The `demo/FR-gnupg-1.4.13.c` file in this directory uses the following statement:

```
    #include <mastik/symbol.h>
    #include <mastik/ff.h>
    #include <mastik/util.h>
```

But none of these three are standard libraries. Why use `<>`, not `"`". I also don't see a directory being added to the search path in this Makefile.

I wrote a main.c file myself:

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include <mastik/util.h>



int main(){
  

  printf("hello,world\n");
  return 0;

}
```

If I execute:  `gcc -g -L../src/ -g  main.c -o main  -lmastik -ldwarf -lelf -lbfd`
main.c:17:25: fatal error: mastik/util.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Such an error will occur.

Comment: Regarding your first question, please read about [built-in rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules).

Comment: Thanks! I also verified it in the Makefile. Indeed, when %:%.o is used, .o is automatically generated.

Comment: It's not immediately clear if the Makefile shown above is generated or not, but any project that hard- codes `prefix` and fails to honor DESTDIR  is a project to be avoided (or fixed).

Comment: The above Makefile is generated, will this make a difference? 
After this Makefile is generated, is it different from the Makefile with the same content that we hand-written?

Comment: "*I am compiling under the demo directory*" -- this may very well be a mistake.  Build systems for large or complex projects often are not intended to be entered other than at the top level.  It might work correctly, or it might not.

Comment: I first executed ./configure --prefix=my_path && make && make install in the top directory. Then the Makefile is generated, and then I execute make in the demo directory.

Comment: You really helped me a lot. thank you very much. I now specify the directory I specified when ./configure was executed, and specify it with -I when compiling, and it has now succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Before running make, there is no `.o` file in the folder, and there is no command to generate a `.o` file in this Makefile, only the
>    command to generate executable files from the .o file. However, when
>    executing, the `.o` file will be generated first, and the executable
>    file will be generated. Where is the control to generate `.o` files?

`make` provides built-in rules for some common patterns.  Among these is a rule for building `.o` files from corresponding `.c` files.  These will be considered when the makefile does not provide an explicit rule applicable to building a needed target.

> 2. The `demo/FR-gnupg-1.4.13.c` file in this directory uses the following statement:
>
>    ```
>    #include <mastik/symbol.h>
>    #include <mastik/ff.h>
>    #include <mastik/util.h>
>    ```
>
> But none of these three are standard libraries. Why use `<>`, not `""`.

Since it's in the `demo/` directory, it is presumably intended as an example of how a third party would use the library *after it is installed to the system*.  In that context, the `<>` is probably the most appropriate stylistic choice.

> I
> also don't see a directory being added to the search path in this
> Makefile.

It may be that the `demo/` files are not intended to be built as part of a normal build of the project.  The Makefile would then itself be part of the demo.  It would probably work once the library is installed to the system.

Additionally / alternatively, mind my comment on the question.  It may not be intended that the makefile in the `demo/` directory be used directly.  If this directory is entered via recursive `make` starting from the top-level makefile, then I would expect the needed flags to be provided contextually, by environment variables or variables set in the recursive `make` commands.  This is absolutely my expectation if, as you seem to say in comments, the project has an Autotools-based build system.

Comment: Thank you! When I execute make in the top directory, it recursively calls the Makefile in the demo directory. This is in line with your explanation. But I can execute make clean in the demo directory alone, and then execute make, and the compilation is successful at this time.  This is very strange. Since the Makefile in the demo directory does not add the include path, why can it be executed alone?

Comment: @Gerrie, the makefile you present for the demo directory contains `CFLAGS=-g -O2   -I..`.  It appears that the `-I..` is appropriate for locating the headers *in the source tree*, relative to the demo sources.  So yes, the makefile *does* add the include path.